# Cloth simulation not covered the object below

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

i have some problem with cloth simulation

i try with basic shape (Uv Sphere) it can work properly, but when i try using my custom shape it go through inside the object instead of covered the object. I use the same setting on cloth adn collision

here the image sample (UV Sphere)

[image: with UV Sphere]

and this is for the custom one
[image]

Comment: did you delete your bakes? if yes, please provide blend file

Comment: What is the shape in the collision settings? Has the collision mesh the correct size? 1*1*1? (Control+a, size)

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for your response, here is the link for the blend file. hope you can get whats wrong with my object since i just about to learn using blender.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nWWrFAxTs__MscR0g7TdoqCdGyLGb7y3/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Also try using **pin** option in the cloth sim panel. The result, due to a vertex group, is like a cloth hanging on a hook.

Answer (score 0):

Plane:

1. change cloth quality steps to 10
2. shade smooth
3. delete all bakes
4. change collision quality to 10

Circle:

uncheck override normals and single sided

result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Big thanks! Really appreciate for your kindness!

Comment: you are welcome. if my answer helped you, please check the checkmark left to my answer. Thank you.